# 2 column css layout without faux column

Tags: layout, css

I know the common solution to this problem is the faux layout, but that doesn't work for me because I have a section with a shadow that needs to extend over the sidebar. Are there any new work arounds for this issue? I'd like this content section to always be 100% of the #main, so the sidebar doesn't extend below it.

I've included the entire HTML / CSS.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        * {
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: #ccc;
        }
        #content {
           width: 900px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            background: #fff;
        }
        #main {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #sidebar {
            width: 180px;
            float: left;
        }
        #sidebar li {
           padding: 10px;
           border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
        }
        #main-content {
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            float: left;
            width: 700px;
            padding: 10px
        }


    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <ul>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                  <li>Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main-content">I'd like this content section to always be 100% of the #main, so the sidebar doesn't extend below it.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm lazy, put this in a jsfiddle for me.

Comment: I'm curious, in your use case can your sidebar be longer than your content as well as your content to be longer than your sidebar?  I'm not visualizing how a faux column couldn't work.  If it's because of needing 2 background images you can always add another DIV wrapper as hm. answered below and CSS3 has multiple background images with what looks like decent support (http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple backgrounds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery for this:

`$("#main-content").height($("#sidebar").height() - 20);`

`-20` is the padding you applied.

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/DEVha/

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a div wrapper with a background image. inside of this wrapper, you place the two floating divs under the two floating divs - but still inside of the wrapper - you kill the float with the following line:

```
<div style="clear: both; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp;</div>
```